# Zend Framework dynamic action name routing

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

My site lets you create projects, and there are multiple project types (like project templates).

What I want to do is to have one single action that handles all project types. Currently for each project type I have a separate action and view. I want to route them all to one single action.

Here's what I've come up with so far, that doesn't work.

```
resources.router.routes.new_project.route = "/project/new-:id"
resources.router.routes.new_project.defaults.controller = "project"
resources.router.routes.new_project.defaults.module = "site"
resources.router.routes.new_project.defaults.action = "new"
resources.router.routes.new_project.reqs.id = "([0-9]+)"
```

So I want my URLs to look like `http://mysite.com/project/new-1` or `http://mysite.com/project/new-2`, where 1 and 2 are the project type IDs. Both these URLs should be mapped to the action called `new` in the `project` controller.

Is something like this possible in ZF 1.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired URL format can easily be achieved with a regular expression route:

```
resources.router.routes.new_project.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.new_project.route = "project/new-(\d+)"
resources.router.routes.new_project.defaults.controller = "project"
resources.router.routes.new_project.defaults.module = "site"
resources.router.routes.new_project.defaults.action = "new"
resources.router.routes.new_project.map.1 = "project_type_id"
resources.router.routes.new_project.reverse = "project/new-%s"
```

You can then access the ID using `$this->_getParam('project_type_id')` in your controller.

Comment: *Almost* what I've come up with. This didn't work for me so in `new_project.route` I removed the beginning slash, and ended up with `^project/new-(\d+)`.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, I've removed those from my answer. ZF actually strips them off before doing the route matching, but you may have ended up with a double slash in the assembled route.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you cannot specify URL variables as parts - they must occupy the whole of the segment (where a segment is delimited by `/`) - that is, the first character must be a `:` and the name is then the remainder of the value.

See function `__construct` in `Zend/Controller/Router/Route.php` (lines 158..196) - it only checks if `substr($part, 0, 1)` matches `:`, (rather than looking for it anywhere within the segment).

I think this means you would need to use `/project/new/:id` in Zend to use the same action - you can potentially use mod_rewrite in Apache to have URLs like `/project/new-(\d+)` presented to the user but rewritten to `/project/new/$1` for Zend.

Comment: +1 for what seems like a working solution. I found something that works for me from Zend's `application.ini` file. Will post later. Thank you!